# Android - which callback is called first, onConnected(from the google play services) or onCreateOptionsMenu when creating an activity

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-progressbar

Which callback in the android lifecycle is called first, is it the onConnected or onCreateOptionsMenu. I have a progress bar in the menu of my activity which get created in the onCreateOptionsMenu and I am storing a global reference to that menu object in that function. I am also using the google play services onConnected callback where I am starting a timer task which uses that menu object. But the catch here is I get a Null Pointer Exception at times as I believe the onConnected Google play services callback gets called before the onCreateOptionsMenu. What do you all think? Here is some sample code.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

        }
    }, 0l, 1000 * 1 * 10);

}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // Bug, throws NPE at times, progressSpinner
            progressSpinner = menu.findItem(R.id.refresh_button);
            progressSpinner.setActionView(R.layout.progess_bar_layout);
            progressSpinner.expandActionView();
            ....
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_all_top_menu_bar, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why does it matter? One inflates the `OptionsMenu` and the other from `Google Play Services` will tell you whether the user is connected or not. You do not need a `try/catch` around your `getMenuInflater`.

Comment: So in the onConnected Callback I am getting the users location and then calling a backend server API for which I want to update the progress bar in the optionsMenu

Comment: Also the try/catch is there, as I was trying to add some synchronization but it did not work. Let me remove those try/catch blocks

Comment: You have a progress bar in your options menu? This is the options menu: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xFlzp.png. Why would you have a progress bar in there.

Comment: Good point, I have it in the action bar not in the options menu. I think I just got carried away by the name "optionsMenu". Sorry about that. This is what I am trying to do

Comment: http://cdn3.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/android-action-bar-adding-custom-view-refresh-progress-bar.png?ca6731

Comment: That is the old way of doing "refresh". Why not use the newer APIs that came with Support v4 such as `SwipeRefreshLayout`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html. This is what Gmail uses with it's Material Design.

Comment: Here is what I am talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl8czoZtXVE.

Comment: That looks nice. Let me try that